# 404 Error not hitting Global.asax in Prod but it is in Test

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a custom .net 404 page and when it redirects, it is supposed to log the 404 error in our db and send an email.  This works in Test, but not in Prod.  I can't locate any difference in the setups.

**Test**:
Sends Email
Logs
Redirects

**Prod:**
Redirects, but no logging or email

Any ideas where to look and correct this behavior?

Here is the snippet in the config file.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect='~/Error.aspx'>
  <error statusCode="403" redirect='Default.aspx' />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect='404.aspx' />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're not going to be able to log the errors from the custom error page in production. Maybe these can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-asp-net-health-monitoring-cs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs

Comment: Check your database connection string and smtp settings in production environment.